# Error when installing torch through requirements.txt for azure web service deployment

Tags: python, azure, flask, visual-studio-code, torch

Generating a requirements.txt file returns this for torch:

> torch==1.6.0+cpu
> torchvision==0.7.0+cpu

However, with +cpu, I get an error that it is not able to find what it is supposed to install.
I navigated to this website: https://pypi.org/project/torch/#history and since I couldnt find any version saying "+cpu" so I removed the +cpu from my requirements.txt file and ran the deployment again.

**Now this is where it is stuck at:**
Collecting torch==1.6.0
9:41:06 PM cv-web-app: [16:41:06+0000]   Downloading torch-1.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (748.8 MB)
It is taking forever to install this and in the end I keep on getting this error:

> An unknown error has occurred. Check the diagnostic log for details.

I see the diagnostic logs through the azure portal and I dont see anything logged beyond the installing of torch. As in I am unable to figure out what the error is. Maybe I am mistaking in my checking.

How do I figure out what is wrong? What does the CPU indicate?

Moreover, I am making a computer vision app. Using flask, and my system is windows. I am deploying it to azure through vscode through the "Create new web app" option.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ryanchill , When we deploy our Python app, Azure App Service will create a virtual environment and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.
If its not happening, make sure `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` is set to `1`.

[image]

See  [Configure a Linux Python app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python) for more details.

**NOTE: Also as mentioned in the above MS DOC**

[image]

You can [install using path](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29745#issuecomment-553606289)  with putting the `pytorch` path in the **`requirements.txt`**

For example:

```
  --find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html torch==1.9.0+cpu
```

**Reference:**
. [Python Webapp on Azure - PyTorch | MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/491500/python-webapp-on-azure-pytorch.html) .

Also please refer the below links for more information:

. [MS Tutorial: Deploy Python apps to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01)

.[Blog PyTorch Web Service deployment using Azure Machine Learning Service and Azure Web Apps from VS Code](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/pytorch-web-service-deployment-using-azure-machine-learning-service-and-azure-web-apps-from-vs-code-a1ba75e43520)